# Bugzilla search result is too long

Tags: search, bugzilla

Suppose I want to search for bugs reported in recent 2 years. The initial result page says "*This result was limited to 500 bugs*"

Apparently there are more than 500 bugs, so I click `See all search results for this query`. This time, it shows 10000 bugs, but with a message saying "*This list is too long for Bugzilla's little mind; the Next/Prev/First/Last buttons won't appear on individual bugs*"

So my question is:

1. How do I know the exact number of bugs returned by my query (it's unlikely to be exactly 10000)
2. How do I view the entire search results? Currently it seems like if the search results exceed 10000, the results are truncated. And I didn't find any `prev/next page` button to navigate the search results page.

Answer (score 4):

You may not see all the bugs because of the configuration your administrator set on your bugzilla instance.

However, using the [search](http://www.bugzilla.org/docs/4.4/en/html/api/Bugzilla/WebService/Bug.html#search) function from the bugzilla webservice you can retrieve the list of bugs. If the number of bugs returned by the query is capped, then iterate on the search query using a higher `offset` and `limit`. Here is some pseudocode

```
offset = 0
limit = 5000
currentcount = ws.search(criterias, offset, limit).count
while currentcount == limit
{
    offset += limit
    currentcount = ws.search(criterias, offset, limit).count
}
totalbugs = currentcount + offset
```

The same algorithm would work if you also wanted to get the whole list of bugs instead of just the count.

If the idea of sending multiple queries to the webservice don't feel right you may have to talk to the admin to know what hard limits are set on your install of bugzilla and see how you can tweak them to get the results you need

Comment: [Here](http://codehelpline.blogspot.com/2010/08/how-to-access-bugzilla-webservice-api.html) is help on how to consume Bugzilla Webservice via XML-RPC from java code.